# Namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods (DayNight)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I made a day and night script for Unity 3D 5, and it was working fine until I accidentally deleted it. I copied the script and now I am getting the error "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods).

```
var cyclemins : float; 
var cyclecalc : float; 

cyclemins = 12;
cyclecalc = 0.1/cyclemins *-1;

function Update () {
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, cyclecalc, Space.World);
}
```

Here is a link to the file on mediafire http://www.mediafire.com/download/bbeu88jido8x82n/DayNight.cs

For my setup:
Dell XPS 8500
Windows 10
Monodevelop (Tried visual studio 2015 but monodevelop was better, transfered file)
Dual Monitors

Unity 3D 5

Comment: this doesn't even look like C#, I suggest take something even more beginner friendly than Unity. When posting on SO provide all relevant data, code, setup etc - like the entire code file you're working on (if not too big)

Comment: Before you post your questions on SO please **read all help center rules and suggestions. Do not ignore helping text  when you create your question**

Comment: Is your code wrapped inside a `class`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using js language on a cs file. The compiler is complaining that this is not right.

If you use it in Js file it works fine. In C#, you cannot use a variable while declaring another one. You'd have to change the syntax and move some of it in Start.

```
public class MyClass:MonoBehaviour{
   float cyclemins = 12f; 
   float cyclecalc = 0f; 

   void Start(){
      cyclecalc = 0.1/cyclemins *-1;
   }

   void Update () {
      transform.Rotate(0, 0, cyclecalc, Space.World);
   }
}
```